# Which is more efficient, storing output in variable or output to file?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am using Robocopy in PowerShell to sort through and output millions of filenames older than a user-specified age. My question is this: Is it better to make use of Robocopy's logging feature, then import the log via `Get-Content -ReadCount`, or would it be better to store Robocopy's output in a variable so that the script doesn't have to write to disk?

I would have to regex either way to get the actual file names. I'm using Robocopy because many of the files have paths longer than 248 chars.

Is one way more preferred than the other? Don't want to miss something that should be considered obvious.

Comment: The only way to benchmark something is to actually do it both ways with your own data, and compare results. Anything that doesn't actually do so is just speculation.

Comment: Let me ask this...how many times after storing the output will it have to be read again during the life of that process?

Comment: Why are you using Robocopy for this purpose? Why not use PowerShell?

Comment: @Trevor: The question says " I'm using Robocopy because many of the files have paths longer than 248 chars."

Comment: Ah, missed that line.

Comment: I would assume that the variable would be faster, since robocopy is already slamming the disk and therefor I/O would be a bottleneck. The pedant in me would ask "How often do I do this? If I log to a file, will it fill the disk? If the log file is within a path that robocopy will search, will it cause problems?" and other things

Comment: @BrantUnger: I will only use the unformatted output once. The output gets regexed (to get file name and size) and stored into an array so it can be used to modify the attributes of the files or straight out purge the files.

Comment: @Eris: I'm giving it plenty of disk space, so that shouldn't be an issue. And the log file will not be in a location that Robocopy is searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much output you're talking about, and what your available system resources are.  It will be faster to write them out to a file and then read them back in if the disk I/O time is less than the additional overhead required for memory managment to get into memory.  You can try it both ways and time it, but I'd try reading it into memory first while monitoring it with Task Manager.  If it starts throwing lots of page faults, that's a clue that you may be better off using the disk as intermediate storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip all the theory and speculation about the multiple factors in play by measuring how long each method takes using **Measure-Command**, for example:

`Measure-Command {$rc_output = robocopy <arguments>}`

`Measure-Command {robocopy <arguments> /log:rc.log; Get-Content rc.log [...]}`

You'll get output telling you exactly how long each version took, down to the millisecond. Try it out on a small amount of sample data, see which one is quicker, then apply it to your millions of files.

Comment: Trying it with a small sample will always result in faster results saving to a variable.  The performance issues caused by memory exhaustion won't show up until you start scaling it to enough data  for memory management to get involved.

Answer (score 2):

I will add to @mjolinor's comment, and the other comments. To answer the question directly:

Saving information to a variable (and therefore to RAM) is always faster than direct to disk. **But** only in the following situations:

Variables are designed to be used to store small (<10Mb) amounts of data. They are not designed to hold things like entire databases. If the size of the data is large (i.e. millions of rows of data, i.e. tens of megabytes), then disk is always better. The problem is that if you shove a ton of information into a variable, you will fill up your RAM, and once your RAM is full, things slow down, paging memory to disk starts happening, and basically everything stops working, including any commands that you currently running (i.e. Robocopy).

Overall, because you are dealing with millions of rows, my recommendation is to write it to disk, because your results are likely to take up quite a bit of space, much more than a variable "should" hold.

Now, after saying all that and delving into the details of how programs manipulate bits in memory, it all doesn't really matter, because the time spent writing things to disk is very very small compared to the amount of time that it takes to process all the files.

If you are processing 1,000,000 files, and you process them at a good speed, say, 1,000 files a second, then it will take 1,000 seconds to process. That means that it takes over 16 Minutes to run through all the files.

If lets say writing to disk is bad, and causes you to be able to process 5 files slower per second, so 995 files instead, it will run only 5 seconds longer. 5 seconds is an impact of 0.5% which is nothing compared to the amount of time it takes to run the whole process.

It is much more likely that writing to a variable will cause much more troubles than writing to disk.

Comment: Can you provide a source that states that variables are designed to store less than 10MB of data?

Comment: It's more of my own personal limit since technically .NET objects can be up to 2 GB in size. It's not that I am against having big variables, it's more that it's a good point for you to evaluate if this is the "right" way to do things. Variables are used to -process- data, and are not meant to permanently -store- data. So things like logging where you want to store data, really shouldn't be in variables it should be stored to disk. When you want to process the data, then it is better to process it line by line from the file, then to load the entire file in memory, and then process it.